# Mongodb $unwind array of arrays in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB driver: 4.2.6,
Mongoose: ^5.9.6

I want to unwind keyword properties:

```
[
 {
    "_id": null,
    "totalNumberOfData": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "numberOfData": 2,
            "sentiment": "Good",
            "keyword": [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
{
    $unwind: {
      path: "$data.keyword",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
```

How to unwind keyword array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general input to `$unwind` stage should be an array, Since you're doing `data.keyword` unwind is expected a field named `data` as an object with nested field named `keyword` as an array like :`{data : keyword : []}` & it's not able to find it that way which results in an empty array as output of aggregation. As `data` is also an array, you need to unwind it first, So double unwind is needed in your case :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$data",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$data.keyword",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e5Tky-QlVgQ)